# Visual Command Prompt commands not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have VS17 installed and have been studying C# for a while. Ever since I began, I was asked to run the ildasm.exe application, but that didn't work since in my Visual Stidio Command Prompt, when I type ildasm or ildasm.exe, it just says that the command doesn't exist.

I was able to curb that by adding the ildasm.exe application directly to the "Tools" menu of VS17 and accessing it from there and I also copied the path to the "Environment path" so that I could access it through PowerShell directly.

But now I'm being asked to access another application called dumpbin.exe, which has the same problem I initially had with ildasm.exe in the Visual Command Prompt, but this one I simply can't find the path in order to access it and I've googled and searched this website in search of the path, but I only found it for older versions of VS,  which were of no use and running a search through my machine I wasn't able to find it either.

Can anyone help me find what is wrong with my Visual Command Prompt that makes these commands not available?l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With proper installation of VS you should have no problem with running `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017` and access all the commands from there.

[image]

So maybe you should check it if there are no issues there.

With [`DUMPBIN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1h23y6c.aspx) there might be a different case. It is part of C/C++ Build tools so you might not have them installed. Open the VS installer and check if you have this part on your machine.

[image]

And the path that this tool is installed is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX86\x86\dumpbin.exe